# Firebase HIPAA compliance database setup

Tags: node.js, encryption, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hipaa

I am working on a medical related web solution where the application keeps patient's data (name, diagnoses, etc...), and we are using `firebase`'s real time database for this. We have tried to formulate some solutions to comply to HIPAA standards.

1. Put the name data to a different `HIPAA compliant` database provider like Google Cloud, then the rest of the data to firebase.
2. Encrypt the name data in firebase, where the data are being encrypted and decrypted on a `nodejs` server.
3. Encrypt the `keys` and/or `uid`'s related to the patient's records. The data are being encrypted and decrypted on a `nodejs` server.

   ```
   names:{
       encrypted_uid:{
           firstName: 'Sheldon',
           middleName: 'Lee',
           lastName: 'Cooper'
       }
   }
   ```

Though these solution seems to work I am still skeptical to the setup.

Is there a known and an actual `HIPAA compliant` solution for this?

Comment: There isn't. We have an insurance app and other than super basic customer or patient info, you cannot use Firebase to store *anything* remotely related to patient information, even if it's encrypted. There are a very select few HIPAA compliant online storage services but for the most part you need to store everything in it and not link to outside data (or vice versa)

Comment: Exactly what I have heard from forums. Thanks @Jay Anyways this is not related to my question, can you suggest a good way to encrypt a key in nodejs? Is bcrypt good enough?

Comment: @CENT1PEDE I'm also in the same boat, are you still using firebase with conjuction with bcrypt?

Comment: @jasan Yes I'm  still using `bcrypt` to encrypt the id to de-identify the connection of sensitive data to the user who own it. If you're interested I'm going to write a glog about it on my website, you can just contact me there if you need more help. :) My website is https://randomcodetips.com